# Keyboard animation issue on iOS 7 devices

Tags: ios, ios7, uiwebview, cordova-3

I was working with Xcode 4.6 with iOS 6 SDK for building our iOS app. Recently we migrated to Xcode 5 which comes with iOS 7 built-in. After migrating to iOS 7 SDK, lot of weird things are happening e.g. status bar issue, keyboard animation mess up and UIImagePickerController status bar issue.

I am not finding any solution for the weird keyboard animation issue. When I tap the username text field in my login screen, entire view is going up till the text field and its not scrollable also. Its totally screwed up. Please note that mine is a hybrid application built using cordova library. So, all the UI elements are designed in HTML5. Below are two screenshots for the key board issue.

Please suggest me how to fix this… Thanks in advance….

Answer (score 2):

That seems to be a problem in web view's on iOS7.  We have the same problem.
It seems fixed in iOS 7.1.

Comment: Thanks…. That may be one of the reason… But as iOS 7.1 has not yet released, is there any work around for this now? Because our app is going to app store next month and we can not go live with this for sure.

Comment: I don't know of any, but I don't know HTML5 either.